# Creating a SSRS report using a mySQL data source

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I need to setup a report server using SQL Server Reporting Services with MySQL datasource. I am using a ODBC connection to connect MySQL. Using this connection I am able to add a dataset in my reporting project in Visual Studio 2015.

Using this dataset I can create a reports in Visual Studio and it show me preview as well using my table from MySQL, So far so good only problem arise when I try to deploy my reports to my local machine it show following error :

> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express Edition and I follow this tutorial to connect report with MySql.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2615/creating-a-ssrs-report-using-a-mysql-data-source/

Can you please help me to know what I am doing wrong here? Any help will be highly appreciated. Please let me know if any other information needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is supported in express dev version.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/feature-supported-and-unsupported-by-ssrs-with-express-advan/

If you have the full version, it can be easily done, via the instructions you linked above.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is this feature not available in higher express edition 2014,2016 etc. Thanks for the answer